# Running Python Code Simultaneously with Video Playback

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, video

I am working on a Python project where I need to play a video using Python, and I want the code below the video playback section to execute simultaneously. Currently, I am using a library like OpenCV to play the video. However, **when the video starts playing, the subsequent codes in my script wait until the video playback is completed before executing.**

I am looking for a way to make the Python code below the video playback section run concurrently with the video playback. This is essential for my project's real-time processing requirements.

Can someone provide an example or guide me on how to play a video and execute the codes below it at the same time?

*Eg:* **Video Playback Code (Using OpenCV, for example):**

```py
import cv2

# Video playback code here
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Codes that should run simultaneously with video playback
# ...

# Real-time processing logic here
# ...
```

its ok to use other libs instead of cv2,
but when playing the video the codes below the video playing codes part also want to work

I appreciate any help or suggestions on how to achieve concurrent execution of the video playback and the subsequent codes in my Python script. Thank you!

Comment: You could utilise [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) to play audio and video simultaneously in your case?

Comment: previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77325147/playing-separate-audio-and-video-files-simultaneously-in-python-seeking-assista (includes recommending pygame)

Answer (score -1):

How about trying the [threading module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)?

```
import cv2
import threading
    
def playback():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')
    while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

play = threading.Thread(target=playback)
play.start()
```

Comment: someone else already suggested that. it does not solve the synchronization problem. making a video player is not as trivial as you might think. also: your code doesn't actually solve anything. it just moves the entire main function into a separate thread. it might as well run in the main thread. this is entirely superfluous.

Comment: @mrithul-e To start the thread I forgot to add play.start()

Comment: please take the [tour]. you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77333595/edit) your answer

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thank you.